# Error running 'Application': -679216128 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am getting this error `Error running 'Application': -679216128` while running my Spring Boot Application. It just doesn't gives any hint as to what could possibly be wrong. I am using community edition.

Can someone please throw some light on what could be the possible resolution?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Console" and idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the console buffer size worked for me.

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Console